# Prevent text overlap in wordpress using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

Please see this page http://www.parentcenterhub.org/region6-aboutus/

I have added a list of links in the right. The CSS is:

```
.custom_list {
position: absolute;
Right: 70px;
top: 30px;
list-style-type: none;}
a.custom1_link { color:rgb(234,150,41); }
```

But, now the main content of page is overlapping with it. I want to keep the width of list to 300px and main content of page should wrap around it. Please tell the right code.

Comment: set width your entry-header and entry content.  And your code is not standard, you use header element. Just use div with class entry-header rather than <header class="entry-header">.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style will be as follow:

```
.custom_list {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}
#primary{
    display: -webkit-box; // or display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented this but now at http://www.parentcenterhub.org/region6-aboutus/ the text is alright but the image in the article doesnt have a left margin and is not displayed correctly.

Comment: Yes.I just corrected it. But, the list still overlaps with footer in http://www.parentcenterhub.org/centers-in-region-6/parent-centers-in-nevada/

Comment: add 

width: 100%;
display: inline-block;

in your css file styleing of class "site-footer"

Comment: Thanks. But now a white strip has appeared below footer. How do I remove this white space http://www.parentcenterhub.org/centers-in-region-6/parent-centers-in-nevada/ ??

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand, what you are explaining. :(

Comment: IF you visit the link given, you will see a white space has appeared below the footer after adding display: inline-block; to "site-footer". How do I remove this white strip below footer?

Comment: Its fixed. I just added "overflow: hidden;" to "site-footer".